# Get a button to align with tabs in ttk.notebook

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an app, where I need to add a `create_new_tab` button, which trails the last tab of the notebook widget. However all my attempts using pack have failed. I have packed the notebook using `pack`.

In the image below, I need the `+++` to trail the last tab

```
import Tkinter as GUI
import ttk
import ScrolledText
import commands

app = GUI.Tk()
lang = ''

class DisplayWidget():
    def __init__(self, book):
        """
        :param book: the tabbed notebook
        :return:
        """
        self.book = book
        self.primary_frame = []
        self.frame_codepad = []
        self.frame_outputpad = []
        self.frame_autocomplete = []
        self.bar_editor = []
        self.lb = []
        self.pad = []
        self.linepad = []
        self.inputpad = []
        self.outputpad = []
        self.W1 = []

    def create_tab(self, *args):

        primary_frame = GUI.Frame(self.book)
        frame_codepad = GUI.Frame(primary_frame)
        frame_autocomplete = GUI.Frame(primary_frame)
        frame_outputpad = GUI.Frame(primary_frame)
        W1 = GUI.PanedWindow(frame_codepad, height=30, width=70)
        bar_editor = GUI.Scrollbar(frame_codepad)
        pad = GUI.Text(W1, height=30, width=60, yscrollcommand=bar_editor.set, undo=True)
        pad.config(fg='#f8f8f2', bg='#002b36', insertbackground='white')
        linepad = GUI.Text(frame_codepad, height=30, width=4, yscrollcommand=bar_editor.set, undo=True)
        linepad.config(fg='#f8f8f2', bg='#002b36', insertbackground='white', state=GUI.DISABLED)
        lb = GUI.Listbox(frame_autocomplete, height=4, width=120)
        lb.config(fg='gray', bg='#002b36')
        inputpad = GUI.Text(W1, height=30, width=30)
        inputpad.config(fg='white', bg='#002b36', insertbackground='white')

        W1.add(pad)
        W1.add(inputpad)

        def share_bar(*event):
            """
            the linenumber abd code textpads share same scrollbar
            :param event: event
            """
            pad.yview(*event)
            linepad.yview(*event)

        bar_editor.config(command=share_bar)

        outputpad = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(frame_outputpad, height=5, width=80)
        outputpad.config(fg='white', bg='#002b36', insertbackground='white', state=GUI.DISABLED)

        primary_frame.pack(side=GUI.LEFT, fill=GUI.BOTH, expand=GUI.YES)
        frame_codepad.pack(side=GUI.TOP, fill=GUI.BOTH, expand=GUI.YES)
        linepad.pack(side=GUI.LEFT, fill=GUI.Y)
        W1.pack(side=GUI.LEFT, fill=GUI.BOTH, expand=GUI.YES)
        bar_editor.pack(side=GUI.LEFT, fill=GUI.Y)
        frame_autocomplete.pack(side=GUI.TOP, fill=GUI.BOTH, expand=GUI.YES)
        lb.pack(side=GUI.TOP, fill=GUI.BOTH, expand=GUI.YES)

        self.book.add(primary_frame, text='untitled.cpp')

        self.primary_frame.append(primary_frame)
        self.frame_codepad.append(frame_codepad)
        self.frame_outputpad.append(frame_outputpad)
        self.frame_autocomplete.append(frame_autocomplete)
        self.bar_editor.append(bar_editor)
        self.lb.append(lb)
        self.pad.append(pad)
        self.linepad.append(linepad)
        self.inputpad.append(inputpad)
        self.outputpad.append(outputpad)
        self.W1.append(W1)

    def destroy_tab(self):
        index = self.book.index(self.book.select())
        self.book.forget(self.book.select())
        self.primary_frame.pop(index)
        self.frame_codepad.pop(index)
        self.frame_outputpad.pop(index)
        self.frame_autocomplete.pop(index)
        self.bar_editor.pop(index)
        self.lb.pop(index)
        self.pad.pop(index)
        self.linepad.pop(index)
        self.inputpad.pop(index)
        self.outputpad.pop(index)
        self.W1.pop(index)


def main():
    commands.setKeys()
    display = commands.CodeDisplay()
    cmd_file = commands.FilesFileMenu()
    edit = commands.EditFileMenu()
    run = commands.RunFilemenu()

    book = ttk.Notebook(app)

    def useless():
        print 'sexy'

    def index():
        return book.index(book.select())

    def change_lang(newlang):
        """
        changes current language in editor
        :param newlang: language to switch to
        :return:
        """
        global lang
        lang = newlang
        # r = map(str, app.title().split('.'))
        # if lang == 'c++' and r[-1] == 'py':
        #     app.title('untitled.cpp')
        #     cmd_file.set_new_filedetails('untitled.cpp', os.getcwd() + '/untitled.cpp')
        #     print File.name, File.path
        # if lang == 'py' and r[-1] == 'cpp':
        #     app.title('untitled.py')
        #     cmd_file.set_new_filedetails('untitled.py', os.getcwd() + '/untitled.py')

    change_lang('c++')

    code = DisplayWidget(book)
    code.create_tab()

    menubar = GUI.Menu(app)
    filemenu = GUI.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label='New', command=useless)
    filemenu.add_command(label='New Tab', command=lambda: cmd_file.create_new_tab(code))
    filemenu.add_command(label='Close Tab', command=lambda: cmd_file.close_tab(code))
    filemenu.add_command(label='Open', command=lambda: cmd_file.Open(
        app, book, code.pad[index()], code.linepad[index()], lang))
    filemenu.add_command(label='Save', command=lambda: cmd_file.Save(
        app, code.pad[index()]))
    filemenu.add_command(label='Save As', command=lambda: cmd_file.Save_As(
        app, code.pad[index()]))
    filemenu.add_command(label='Exit', command=cmd_file.Exit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=filemenu)

    editmenu = GUI.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    editmenu.add_command(label='Undo - (ctrl+z)', command=lambda: edit.undo(
        code.pad[index()], code.linepad[index()]))
    editmenu.add_command(label='Redo - (ctrl+r)', command=lambda: edit.redo(
        code.pad[index()], code.linepad[index()]))
    menubar.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=editmenu)

    runmenu = GUI.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    runmenu.add_command(label='Compile - (F7)', command=lambda: run.compile(
        app, code.pad[index()], code.outputpad[index()], lang, code.frame_outputpad[index()]))
    runmenu.add_command(label='Run - (F5)', command=lambda: run.run(
        app, code.pad[index()], code.outputpad[index()], code.inputpad[index()], lang, code.frame_outputpad[index()]))
    menubar.add_cascade(label='Run', menu=runmenu)

    langmenu = GUI.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    langmenu.add_radiobutton(label='c++', command=lambda: change_lang('c++'))
    langmenu.add_radiobutton(label='python', command=lambda: change_lang('py'))
    menubar.add_cascade(label='Language', menu=langmenu)

    app.bind('<Escape>', lambda event: display.escape(
        code.frame_autocomplete[index()], code.pad[index()], event))
    app.bind('<Down>', lambda event: display.select_first(
        code.frame_autocomplete[index()], code.lb[index()], code.pad[index()], event))

    code.frame_autocomplete[index()].bind('<Return>', lambda event: display.insert_word(
        code.frame_autocomplete[index()], code.pad[index()], code.lb[index()], lang, event))

    code.pad[index()].bind('<Tab>', lambda event: display.tab_width(code.pad[index()], event))

    app.bind('<KeyPress>', lambda event: display.show_in_console(
        app, book, event, code.pad[index()], code.linepad[index()], lang, code.lb[index()],
        code.frame_codepad[index()], code.W1[index()], code.bar_editor[index()],
        code.frame_outputpad[index()], code.frame_autocomplete[index()], code.outputpad[index()]))

    app.bind('<space>', lambda event: display.add_to_trie(
        code.frame_autocomplete[index()], code.pad[index()], code.lb[index()], event))
    app.bind('<Return>', lambda event: display.indentation(
        code.pad[index()], code.linepad[index()], lang, event))
    app.bind('<F7>', lambda event: run.compile(
        app, code.pad[index()], code.outputpad[index()], lang, code.frame_outputpad[index()], event))
    app.bind('<F5>', lambda event: run.run(
        app, code.pad[index()], code.outputpad[index()], code.inputpad[index()],
        lang, code.frame_outputpad[index()], event))

    app.bind('<Control-r>', lambda event: edit.redo(
        code.pad[index()], code.linepad[index()], lang, event))
    app.bind('<Control-z>', lambda event: edit.undo(
        code.pad[index()], code.linepad[index()], lang, event))
    app.bind('<BackSpace>', lambda event: display.fast_backspace(
        code.pad[index()], code.linepad[index()], event))

    new_tab_button = GUI.Button(book,text = '+++')
    new_tab_button.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

    book.pack(side=GUI.TOP, fill=GUI.BOTH, expand=GUI.YES)
    app.config(menu=menubar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    app.title('untitled.cpp')
    app.mainloop()
```

[image: app]

Comment: Do you think maybe it would be helpful to show us some of your program's code?

Comment: oh, so silly , edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can get the button to trail the last tab of the Notebook. So what I suggest is using a tab as a button instead.

Example Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def add_tab(event):
    all_tabs = note.tabs() # gets tuple of tab ids
    sel = note.select() # gets id of selected tab

    # if the selected tab is the last tab in the Notebook
    if sel == all_tabs[-1]:
        # Change the text from '+++' to 'New Tab'
        note.tab(sel, text = 'New Tab')
        # root.nametowidget is used to map the id to widget
        # this shows adding widgets to the existing tab
        tab_id = root.nametowidget(sel)
        tk.Label(tab_id, text = 'This is a new tab').pack()

        # add a new 'New Tab' button
        note.add(tk.Frame(note), text = '+++')

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(250, 250)

note = ttk.Notebook(root, height = 200, width = 200)

note.add(tk.Frame(note), text = '+++')

note.pack()
note.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', add_tab)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found that it's possible to get a button to trail a tab (*much easier to accomplish when tabs are of equal width*)

So basically we need to find out the total combined width of all the tabs, which can be roughly done by taking the length of the text inside each tab. Then all we need to do is to experiment placing the buttons using the `place` manager.

Sample code in python-2 ( Simple case : Here tabs are of equal sizes )

```
python
import Tkinter as GUI
import ttk
from ScrolledText import ScrolledText

class displayWidget():
    def __init__(self,book):
        self.frame1 =[]
        self.pad1 = []
        self.pad2 = []
        self.book = book

    def foo(self,pad2,event):
        pass
    def create_tab(self,*args):
        frame1a = GUI.Frame(self.book)
        pad1a = GUI.Text(frame1a,height = 10,width = 90)
        pad2a = GUI.Text(frame1a,height = 10,width = 90)
        frame1a.pack(side=GUI.TOP)
        pad1a.pack(side=GUI.TOP)
        pad2a.pack(side=GUI.TOP)
        pad2a.bind('<KeyPress>',lambda event: self.foo(pad2a,event))

        self.frame1.append(frame1a)
        self.pad1.append(pad1a)
        self.pad2.append(pad2a)
        name = '   Tab   '
        self.book.add(frame1a,text=name)
        self.book.pack(side=GUI.TOP)

    def destory_tab(self,*args):
        index = self.book.index(self.book.select())
        self.book.forget(self.book.select())
        self.frame1.pop(index)
        self.pad1.pop(index)
        self.pad2.pop(index)



app = GUI.Tk()
book = ttk.Notebook(app)
D = displayWidget(book)
new_tab_button = GUI.Button(book,text='+',bg='#228c22',fg='white')
del_tab_button = GUI.Button(book,text='-',bg='red',fg='white')

def add_tab(*args):
    D.create_tab()
    new_tab_button.place_forget()
    new_tab_button.place(x = 50+ 46*(len(book.tabs())-1), y = -0.5)
    del_tab_button.place_forget()
    del_tab_button.place(x = 69 + 46*(len(book.tabs())-1), y = -0.5)

def remove_tab(*args):
    if len(book.tabs()) == 1:
        return
    D.destory_tab()
    new_tab_button.place_forget()
    new_tab_button.place(x = 50+ 46*(len(book.tabs())-1), y = -0.5)
    del_tab_button.place_forget()
    del_tab_button.place(x = 69 + 46*(len(book.tabs())-1), y = -0.5)

D.create_tab()
new_tab_button.bind('<Button-1>',add_tab)
del_tab_button.bind('<Button-1>',remove_tab)
new_tab_button.place(x = 50, y = -0.5)
del_tab_button.place(x = 69, y = -0.5)
app.resizable(height=False,width=False)
app.mainloop()
```